# Differentiate full refund vs partial refund

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to differentiate between full refund vs partial refund. There is no flag in SQL database thus this request. Little explanation about data.There could be full refund or partial refund to the customers. Full refund is refund of full amount paid by customer and partial is partial amount refund.

I have 2 tables , Order Header and Order Line (Header table have CustomerId,OrderId, OrderDate, OrderGuid, OrderType,Amount,Reasoncode) 
(line Tabe have CustomerId,OrderId, OrderDate, OrderGuid,ItemNo,Quantity,LineAmount).

When customer orders it will be like something below in Header level:

```
 OrderId   OrderDate   CustomerID   OrderGuid    OrderType  Amount   ReasonCode
  FN1        2018-07-15    1          FN1-1        Sales       50       

  FN2        2018-07-16    2          FN2-1        Sales       100
```

Same at Line level:

```
  OrderId   OrderDate   CustomerID  OrderGuid    ItemNo  LineAmount  Qty
   FN1        2018-07-15    1          FN1-1      123-0     20         1
   FN1        2018-07-15    1          FN1-1      111-0     30         1

   FN2        2018-07-16    2          FN2-1      586-0     40         1
   FN2        2018-07-16    2          FN2-1      482-1     20         1
   FN2        2018-07-16    2          FN2-1      784-1     20         1
   FN2        2018-07-16    2          FN2-1      624-0     20         1
```

When something is refunded Header level:

```
OrderId   OrderDate    CustomerID   OrderGuid      OrderType   Amount   ReasonCode
 FN1        2018-07-20    1          FN1-RF1        Credit       50      Lost_in_post 

 FN2        2018-07-21    2          FN2-RF1        Credit       60      Damaged_in_transit
```

Same at Line leveL:

```
 OrderId   OrderDate    CustomerID  OrderGuid    ItemNo  LineAmount  Qty
 FN1        2018-07-20    1          FN1-RF1    123-0     20         1
 FN1        2018-07-20    1          FN1-RF1    111-0     30         1

 FN2        2018-07-21    2          FN2-RF1    482-1     20         1
 FN2        2018-07-21    2          FN2-RF1    784-1     20         1
 FN2        2018-07-21    2          FN2-RF1    624-0     20         1
```

Note: There is no RefundDate column but still it's OrderDate the date will the day of refund.

Result expecting: I would like to see them in two different tables
          Full refund:

```
 OrderNo      ItemNo    Qty 
 FN1_RF1      123-0       1
 FN1-RF1      111-0       1
```

Partial refund:

```
 OrderNo   ItemNo     Qty
FN2-RF1   482-1       1
FN2-RF1   784-1       1
FN2-RF1   624-0       1
```

Hope this make sense.
Please ask me if you have any question. Thank you in advance.
Best

Comment: If you're considering a partial refund as "part of an order was refunded", why would you put those items into a table? Those items were refunded in full ($20 in, $20 out per item).

Comment: @Eli Original order has 4 items, but the refund was on 3 items hence partial refund.

Comment: I understood that, though if you're looking at the order as a whole, the "full refund" vs the "partial refund" should be on the order level, not on the order item level. One more point, what is the purpose of having the refund items be stored in a separate tables?

Comment: You must also consider refunds on part of a line. If you sent out a 10 `482-1` items on one row, but two were defective and returned for a refund, how do you represent that in your db.  The current structure assumes either one row per individual item or an all-or-nothing return for refund.

Comment: That said, for your current dataset, a simple differential between (rows shipped) and (rows refunded) works to identify full or partial refund. If rows refunded = rows shipped, it is a full refund, otherwise it is a partial refund.

Comment: @LaughingVergil Hi , This is a simple example, you are right sometimes quantity is 2 and refunded only 1.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a recreation of your problem with an example solution,
but a quick question why is FN2-RF1 considered a partial refund? Since the summed line items = the credited amount in your example.

http://rextester.com/EODK86280

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want. You can run the following example in SSMS.

First, create the data you provided for testing.

**Create [header] table and insert data:**

```
DECLARE @header TABLE ( OrderID VARCHAR(10), OrderDate DATETIME, CustomerID INT, OrderGuid VARCHAR(10), OrderType VARCHAR(10), Amount DECIMAL(18,2), ReasonCode VARCHAR(50) );
INSERT INTO @header (
    OrderID, OrderDate, CustomerID, OrderGuid, OrderType, Amount, ReasonCode
) VALUES
( 'FN1', '2018-07-15', 1, 'FN1-1', 'Sales', 50, NULL )
, ( 'FN2', '2018-07-16', 2, 'FN2-1', 'Sales', 100, NULL )
, ( 'FN1', '2018-07-15', 1, 'FN1-RF1', 'Credit', 50, 'Lost_in_post' )
, ( 'FN2', '2018-07-16', 2, 'FN2-RF1', 'Credit', 60, 'Damaged_in_transit' );
```

**Create [line] table and insert data:**

```
DECLARE @line TABLE ( OrderID VARCHAR(10), OrderDate DATETIME, CustomerID INT, OrderGuid VARCHAR(10), ItemNo VARCHAR(10), LineAmount DECIMAL(18,2), Qty INT );
INSERT INTO @line (
    OrderID, OrderDate, CustomerID, OrderGuid, ItemNo, LineAmount, Qty
) VALUES
( 'FN1', '2018-07-15', 1, 'FN1-1', '123-0', 20, 1 )
, ( 'FN1', '2018-07-15', 1, 'FN1-1', '111-0', 30, 1 )
, ( 'FN1', '2018-07-20', 1, 'FN1-RF1', '123-0', 20, 1 )
, ( 'FN1', '2018-07-20', 1, 'FN1-RF1', '111-0', 30, 1 )
, ( 'FN2', '2018-07-12', 2, 'FN2-1', '586-0', 40, 1 )
, ( 'FN2', '2018-07-12', 2, 'FN2-1', '482-0', 20, 1 )
, ( 'FN2', '2018-07-12', 2, 'FN2-1', '784-0', 20, 1 )
, ( 'FN2', '2018-07-12', 2, 'FN2-1', '624-0', 20, 1 )
, ( 'FN2', '2018-07-21', 2, 'FN2-RF1', '482-0', 20, 1 )
, ( 'FN2', '2018-07-21', 2, 'FN2-RF1', '784-0', 20, 1 )
, ( 'FN2', '2018-07-21', 2, 'FN2-RF1', '624-0', 20, 1 );
```

Then we can query against it.

**Full Refunds**

```
SELECT
    ref.OrderGuid, line.ItemNo, line.Qty
FROM @header ref
INNER JOIN @header sale
    ON ref.OrderID = sale.OrderID
    AND sale.OrderType = 'Sales'
INNER JOIN @line line
    ON ref.OrderGuid = line.OrderGuid
WHERE
    ref.OrderType = 'Credit'
    AND ref.Amount = sale.Amount
ORDER BY
    ref.OrderID;
```

Returns

```
+-----------+--------+-----+
| OrderGuid | ItemNo | Qty |
+-----------+--------+-----+
| FN1-RF1   | 123-0  |   1 |
| FN1-RF1   | 111-0  |   1 |
+-----------+--------+-----+
```

**Partial Refunds**

```
SELECT
    ref.OrderGuid, line.ItemNo, line.Qty
FROM @header ref
INNER JOIN @header sale
    ON ref.OrderID = sale.OrderID
    AND sale.OrderType = 'Sales'
INNER JOIN @line line
    ON ref.OrderGuid = line.OrderGuid
WHERE
    ref.OrderType = 'Credit'
    AND ref.Amount < sale.Amount
ORDER BY
    ref.OrderID;
```

Returns

```
+-----------+--------+-----+
| OrderGuid | ItemNo | Qty |
+-----------+--------+-----+
| FN2-RF1   | 482-0  |   1 |
| FN2-RF1   | 784-0  |   1 |
| FN2-RF1   | 624-0  |   1 |
+-----------+--------+-----+
```

Take a look at the **ref.Amount** vs. **sale.Amount** comparisons to see how this works.

Comment: Hi @Critical Error ,I have tried using your code ,it works fine till this point after where clause it does not give any output just column names. I have checked field value' Credit' twice ,yes its available.                                                                                                                     `ON ref.OrderGuid = line.OrderGuid `

Comment: I have replicated this code on database and executed. But your code works perfectly fine when we declare values but not in the database.

Comment: @StevePat, unfortunately, I don't know what your physical database looks like--I did my best to replicate your samples. We can continue this conversation in chat if you'd like and perhaps I can help you further.

Comment: Thank you, Yes can we join in chat??.

Comment: As I am new here ,I don't think I have 20 reputation here to join chat.

Comment: Do you have an email that you can share?

Comment: @ Critical Error, Sure ,it's steve.patrington@gmail.com. Thank you